# Different header (Abstract.php) for invoice and credit memo

Tags: invoice, pdf

Is it possible, and how if it is, to have different header for pdf invoice and pdf credit memo.

In other words is it possible to have separate Abstarct.php. One for pdf invoice and other for pdf credit memo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just implement the `_drawHeader` function in the respective Invoice/CreditMemo subclass and not in the Abstract class...

As always, make sure to create a module for it and do not edit it in the core :-)

By the way, you may want to have a look at [FireGento_Pdf](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf/), which already provides nice-looking PDFs and may also be a good starting point for your custom PDF rendering functionality.

Comment: How would I edit the "Order Date" on the Credit Memo PDF? I've looked everywhere and can't find where to edit it. I was able to edit the date on the Invoice PDF, but not on Credit Memo PDF.